# My Visual Studio Web Form Site loses it's CSS and Minimisation when published

Tags: css, asp.net

I have created an ASP.NET Web Forms Web Site in VS2013
This includes items such as WebGrease and BundleOptimisation

Everything is working perfectly locally on my machine.

But when I publish the website to the actual server, all of the CSS is not being referenced and accessing pages without the .aspx stops working (eg /dashboard instead of dashboard.aspx)

I am running IIS7.1 on the server

Any help would be fantastic. I can't find a solution to this anywhere on the internet but maybe I am typing the wrong search terms!

Comment: How are you attempting to reference the CSS? What's wrong with accessing the pages with .aspx extension? Can you show some example code?

Comment: not sure about IIS but in linux if the rewrite rule is not written properly then /dashboard won't work and then due to which you have to write the extension too to open the file. Not 100% sure but may be. Can i  have the online link to test?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after scouring through solution after solution.

You change "<'module>" to  in the  <'system.webServer> part of the web.config file

That gets the Rewrite working.

And set debug=true in <'compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
So that the CSS works ...

It took so long to fine!